# How to check if input is not number - csh

Tags: unix, if-statement, csh

Please help, I can only see forums with this question for Bash, KSH, and others

Need to apply it on csh.

to check if the inputted $2 is not number nor the word "all"

```
if ($#argv == 2 && ($2 != all && $2 != **any number**)) then
   echo "wrong parameter"
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You posted a similar question, which I answered: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26457720/regex-to-check-if-input-is-number-in-cshunix

Answer (score 0):

this one just search for any letter of _ characted in $2:

```
if ( ($#argv == 2 && $2 != all && `echo $2 | grep -c '[_A-Za-z]') then
     echo "wrong parameter"
endif
```