# regex - to check if input is number in csh(unix)

Tags: regex, unix, if-statement, csh

Please help. How to make regex work in an if condition, 
to check user input(in 2nd parameter) must be not equal to any number?

```
set regex="^[0-9]+$"
if ($#argv == 2 && $2 != $regex) then
# do this
```

Comment: TRy this `if [ $#argv == 2 && ! $2 =~ $regex ]`

Comment: hi, i tried but im getting "**variable syntax**" error now.

Comment: `... && ! $2 =~ "$regex" ] ... ` ? (Note the dbl-quotes surrounding your `regex` variable. Sorry, but I don't have a way to test this). Good luck.

Comment: You guys are trying to use Bash syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**grep-based** solution that only works for **non-negative integers**.

```
#!/bin/csh

# Note this requires 2 command line arguments, and checks the second one
# cshell arguments are 0-indexed.
if ($#argv == 2) then

    # Note the different grep regexp syntax, and you must use single quotes
    set test = `echo $2 | grep '^[0-9]*$'`
    if (($test) || ($test == 0)) then
        echo "Bad input"
    else
        echo "Ok!"
    endif
endif
```

Comment: hi this works fine! but then, it wont include 0. any idea why? but if i put `^[-0-9]*$` it includes negative numbers, but still not 0. thats the only prob now but thanks! kindly help me still if u know the solution thanks!

Comment: It won't include 0 because 0 evaluates to "False" in the the segment `if ($test)`.

Comment: what i did was i put -c option in grep, and retained the rest of the code and it seemed to be working. learned that -c is count, idk but do u think its safe to use the -c option? like this: set test = `echo $2 | grep -c '^[0-9]*$'`

Comment: Looks pretty safe to me. Just remember that neither my solution nor your '-c' idea will match decimals. For that, you need a more complicated regexp.

Comment: its okay, wont include decimals. Thanks!! :)